# Close a set of applications during Idle State - Force Stop

Tags: android, android-intent, accessibility

I need to do a college project, wherein the requirement is to detect the phone idle time and do a force stop on a set of applications. I do get some code that Force Stop's an application using accessibility, but I am unable to understand how the code needs to be triggered.

1. Can a background service achieve the task of stooping a fixed set of applications ?
2. Any code snippet that you can point me too, specially about triggering the accessibility code

Regards,
Buku

Comment: you can create a broadcast receiver for screen off and on then force close the apps like in greenify app or give user control to force close whenever he deems it suitable.

Comment: @trinadhthatakula is there any code reference how it works specially the invocation